# Removing specific characters from a tuple

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have Python code that creates a tuple similar to the following:

```
output = [('50', '5e5e46145a6b8a4a5c8a004217eef836'), ('49',  '2627e0119a8a665e2fd46bc8adc83b31'), ('0', '5746bd7ea0a66a8afa06f7c42c1ba41')]
```

I am using the following code to output my tuple to a CSV, however my output contains the parenthesis and single quotes.  I want my output to simply have each list per line, such as:

```
50, 5e5e46145a6b8a4a5c8a004217eef836

49, 2627e0119a8a665e2fd46bc8adc83b31

0, 5746bd7ea0a66a8afa06f7c42c1ba41
```

I tried using rstrip in the following way, but I'm obviously doing something wrong:

```
output_clean = [tuple((subl[0].rstrip("('"), subl[1].rstrip("')"))) for subl in output]
```

Here is how I am using csv to output the file... maybe I should be doing something different here?

```
out_file = csv.writer(open("results.csv", "wb"), delimiter='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
out_file.writerow(matches_clean)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) instead.

```
output = [('50', '5e5e46145a6b8a4a5c8a004217eef836'), 
          ('49', '2627e0119a8a665e2fd46bc8adc83b31'), 
          ('0', '5746bd7ea0a66a8afa06f7c42c1ba41')]

out_file = csv.writer(open("results.csv", "wb"), 
                      delimiter='\n', 
                      quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
out_file.writerows(output)
```